# how to update JSONB column using knexjs, bookshelfjs

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a JSONB column in PostgreSQL database like `{lat: value, lon: value}`. I want to change any specific value at a time eg. lat, but I am not sure how I can achieve this using bookshelf.js or knex.js. I tried using `jsonb_set()` method specified in Postgres documentation but I am not sure if I used that correctly. Can somebody please suggest me how can I do this? or what is the correct syntax to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK only knex based thing that supports writing to and extracting data from postgresql jsonb columns is objection.js ORM.

With plain knex you need to use raw to write references:

```
knex('table').update({
  jsonbColumn: knex.raw(`jsonb_set(??, '{lat}', ?)`, ['jsonbColumn', newLatValue])
})
```

You can check generated SQL here https://runkit.com/embed/44ifdhzxejf1

Originally answered in: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/2264

More examples how to use jsonb_set with knex can be found in following answers

[How to update a jsonb column's field in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074452/how-to-update-a-jsonb-columns-field-in-postgresql/34721301#34721301)

[What is the best way to use PostgreSQL JSON types with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358082/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-postgresql-json-types-with-nodejs/34865180#34865180)

Comment: How to update json column , using JSON_SET can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331278/how-to-update-a-key-of-object-with-value-in-json-column-with-knexjs, i have tried but all i get is this error json_set(unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Comment: what if i want to update multiple keys in the same field if i did it one by one in the same query update. only the last one updates, i made a question in the link above

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible, unless you create multiple nested jsonb_set function calls where you set each key one by one. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html

Comment: Here is an example how nested jsonb_set queries may be built https://runkit.com/embed/5jw1issuf141

`update \"table\" set \"jsonbColumn\" = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(\"jsonbColumn\", '{key1}', ?, true), '{key2}', ?, true)`

Answer (score 0):

Jsonb field update using knex.js

```
return knex("tablename").update({
        jsonbkey: knex.raw(`
        jsonb_set(jsonbkey, '{city}','"Ayodhya"')
          `)
      }).where({"id" :2020})
```

The `jsonbkey` will be the column name, where the datatype is jsonb.

The `tablename` is the name of your table.

The `city` is the object key.

If there is multiple level of object then you can use dot. Like `'{city.id}'`

Comment: Is the separator for deep paths a dot (`.`), or a comma (`,`)? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/2441655) suggests it is a comma. Maybe both work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let result = await db().raw(`UPDATE widget 
SET name = ?,
jsonCol= jsonCol::jsonb || ?::jsonb
WHERE id = ?`, 
[name, JSON.stringify(newJsonData), id);
```

this knex query helps to update any json column by overriding specific keys in the value supplied to the right hand side of `||` operator. DO NOT forget to typecast the values with `::jsonb`