# How to update a key of object with value in json column with knexjs?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to update a column in users table the column type is **json**.

column name is test.

and the column consists of an object default value for example is

`{a: "text", b: 0}`

how to update let's say the object key `b` without changing the whole column

the code i'm using is

```
knexDb('users').where({
  email: email
})
.update({
  test: { b: 1 }
})
```

second solution

```
knexDb('users').where({
  email: email
})
.update({
  test: knexDb.raw(`jsonb_set(??, '{b}', ?)`, ['test', 1])
})
```

first solution changes the whole column cell and test will be only `{ b: 1 }`

second solution doesn't work it give an error

> function jsonb_set(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist

**The expected result**

is to manage to update only a certain key value in an object without changing the whole object.

**PS**

I also want to update an array that consists of objects like the above one for example.

`[{a: "text", b: 0}, {c: "another-text", d: 0}]`

if i use the code above in kenxjs it'll update the whole array to only `{b: 1}`

**PS** after searching a lot found that in order to make it work i need to set column type to jsonb, in order the above jsonb_set() to work

but now i'm facing another issue

> how to update multiple keys using jsonb_set

```
knexDb('users').where({
      email: email
    })
    .update({
      test: knexDb.raw(`jsonb_set(??, '{b}', ?)`, ['test', 1]),
      test: knexDb.raw(`jsonb_set(??, '{a}', ?)`, ['test', "another-text"]),
    })
```

the first query key b is now not updating, in fact all updates don't work except the last query key `a`, so can some explain why ?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: @felixmosh psql

Comment: If you're using `json` and not `jsonb`, you must pull it out, parse it, change it, stringify it, and then update it. See [docs](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-json)

Comment: I'm hoping they make the `jsonset` querybuilder do this simpler https://github.com/knex/documentation/issues/424

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that you're overwriting `test`. What you're passing into `update` is a JS object ([docs](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-update)). You cannot have multiple keys with identical values ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)). You'll have to do something like this where you make 1 long string with all your raw SQL as the value to `test`.

```
knexDb('users').where({
      email: email
    })
    .update({
      test: knexDb.raw(`
          jsonb_set(??, '{a}', ?)
          jsonb_set(??, '{b}', ?)
        `,
        ['test', "another-text", 'test', 1])
    })
```

Probably a better option exists - one that would be much more readable if you have to do this for several columns is something like what I have included below. In this example, the column containing the `jsonb` is called `json`.

```
const updateUser = async (email, a, b) => {

  const user = await knexDb('users')
    .where({ email })
    .first();

  user.json.a = a;
  user.json.b = b;

  const updatedUser = await knexDb('users')
    .where({ email })
    .update(user)
    .returning('*');

  return updatedUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update/insert a single field in a JSON column:

```
knex('table')
.update( { 
   your_json_col: knex.jsonSet('your_json_col','$.field', 'new value') 
 })
.where(...)
```

### Update/insert multiple fields

**Option 1 (nested)**

```
knex('table')
.update( { 
  your_json_col: knex.jsonSet(knex.jsonSet('your_json_col','$.field1', 'val1')
    '$.field2', 'val2') 
 })
.where(...)
```

**Option 2 (chained)**

```
knex('table')
.update( { 
   your_json_col: knex.jsonSet('your_json_col','$.field1', 'val1') 
 })
.update( { 
   your_json_col: knex.jsonSet('your_json_col','$.field2', 'val2') 
 })
.where(...)
```