# How to access row id while updating jsonb-column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, jsonb

Continuing the question [how to update JSONB column using knexjs, bookshelfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669464/how-to-update-jsonb-column-using-knexjs-bookshelfjs), I would like to update jsob-property not as just a string
but as [string + current row id column value] (the second answer example).

```
return knex("tablename").update({
        jsonbkey: knex.raw(`
        jsonb_set(jsonbkey, '{city}','"Ayodhya ${ROW_ID_COLUMN_HERE}"')
          `)
      }).where({"id" :2020})
```

Is it possible to do this operation during one query?

The second part of my request - how can I perform this query only for row that has those 'city' not as empty string.

```
return knex("tablename").update({
        jsonbkey: knex.raw(`
        jsonb_set(jsonbkey, '{city}','"Ayodhya ${ROW_ID_COLUMN_HERE}"')
          `)
      }).where({"id" :2020}).and.whereNot(jsonbkey.city, '')
```

My rows look like:

```
id | jsonbkey 
1  | {"city": "", code: "EU"}
2  | {"city": "Paris", code: "FR"}
```

I have been thinking about two queries like array_agg for only ids and then loop throw this array - is it rational?